# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm getting this error

```
2023-01-04 15:05:33.297 15984-16060/com.example.food_app E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
    #0      PopularProductController.getPopularProductList (package:food_app/controllers/popular_product_controller.dart:30:71)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      _SplashScreenState._loadResource (package:food_app/pages/splash/splash_page.dart:25:5)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

**popular_product_controller.dart:30:71**

```
Future<void> getPopularProductList()async {
    Response response = await popularProductsRepo.getPopularProductList();
    if(response.statusCode==200) {
      _popularProductList =[];
      _popularProductList.addAll(Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)).products);
      _isloaded=true;
      update();
    }else{
    }
  }
```

**package:food_app/pages/splash/splash_page.dart:25:5**

```
Future<void>_loadResource() async {
    await Get.find<PopularProductController>().getPopularProductList();
    await Get.find<RecommendedProductController>().getRecommendedProductList();

  }
```

.....................

Comment: Can you post your response structure?

Comment: please provide getPopularProductList

Comment: Your model data is mismatched .Kindly check the response with model

Answer (score 0):

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

your output is not matching to model class,
1st check what you get from api after you able to fix this error